# Probability clarification $\chi^2$ distribution table

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having some trouble understanding the solution of this probability question.

> Ammeters produced by a manufacturer are marketed under the specification that the standard deviation of gauge readings is no larger than $.2$ amp. One of these ammeters was used to make ten independent readings on a test circuit with constant current. If the sample variance of these ten measurements is $.065$ and it is reasonable to assume that the readings are normally distributed, do the results suggest that the ammeter used does not meet the marketing specifications? [Hint: Find the approximate probability that the sample variance will exceed $.065$ if the true population variance is $.04$.]

The solution is as follows:

[image]

At the step $P(9S^2 / .04 >= 14.925)$, where does the $.10$ come from. I look at the $\chi^2$ distribution and I'm looking at $9$ degrees of freedom, but I still don't understand.

Comment: Use `$\chi^2$` to show $\chi^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it skipped a step...
$$P\left(\frac{9S^2}{.04}\geq 14.925\right) = 1-P\left(\frac{9S^2}{.04}< 14.925\right)  =1-0.9069832 = 0.09301681$$
which is approximately $.10$ considering possible table rounding errors.
In other words
$$P\left(\frac{9S^2}{.04}\geq 14.925\right)$$
indicates to look at the area to the right, not the left.

Comment: Sorry I am completely out of it today, where does the $0.9069832$ come from?

Comment: @user270494 The value comes from lookup-tables or an [online calculator](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/chiCalc.html)

Comment: @user270494 $P\left(\frac{9S^2}{.04}< 14.925\right)  =0.9069832$ using a calculator, or you could use a table with high accuracy.

Comment: @user270494 Anyway, the value you found using your table, call it $c$. Then I think your answer will match the answer key if you do $1-c$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb P\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\geq \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}\right) = \Bbb P({\raise{0.5ex}{\chi}}^2_{9}\geq 14.925) = ~$[$0.0930...$](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/chiCalc.html) $~\approx 0.1{\small 0}$

The value comes from lookup tables or an online calculator.